# How to load an AMD Module from a Dojo Layer

Tags: javascript, build, dojo, layer, amd

In our application we use dojo for some widgets, including several custom widgets, and use the AMD format for several modules.

e.g.

```
define("foo.bar.module", ["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {

   var module  = declare("foo.bar.module", [], {
      // Do Stuff
   }

   return module;
});
```

This works fine currently, since each module is requested individually. However, we have determined that using a dojo layer, to collapse this into one request would be a good optimisation.

The problem is, that we load the layer upfront, then attempt to require the modules defined in the layer, but the dojo loader cannot find the modules. Is there something in particular needed in the build profile to make this work? Some help, or links to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module IDs are paths, not object identifiers. The first argument to `define` is just wrong; it should be `foo/bar/module` if it is going to exist. However, you should not ever provide the first string argument to `define`, as this breaks portability. You should also not provide the first string argument to `declare` unless you are intentionally trying to create constructors in the global scope.

In summary, your module definition should be:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {

   var module = declare([], {
      // Do Stuff
   }

   return module;
});
```

Finally, there are two important things to note about built layers:

1. Layers are just built modules that also contain additional modules. They should only be created from modules that already exist in your application prior to a build. For example if you have an `app/main` module that you use to load your entire app, that would be a good layer module. Creating a new `app/layerA` module just for a new layer would be wrong.
2. The loader can’t know which modules a layer contains until the layer is loaded. If you build layer "a" with modules "a" "b" and "c", then `require([ "a", "b", "c" ])`, all three modules will be loaded as separate requests because the loader can’t know that "a" contains "b" and "c". In this case you have to always load "a" first, then load "b" and "c" afterwards, at which point they will just be loaded from the layer instead of separately.
3. With the exception of the one layer that has `boot: true` in your build profile (`dojo/dojo`), layers must be loaded the same way as any other module—that is, using `require` or `define`, *not* by including a `<script>` tag for the layer module.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. However, even with these changes, the issue is not resolved. The loader still doesn't find the module when included in the layer. It seems to attempt to make a request and gets a 404

Comment: I added more information. If the more information is not sufficient for you to get an answer, it’s because you haven’t provided your HTML bootstrap, your Dojo configuration, or any other information about your application or how you are trying to load the layer modules.

Comment: Point 3 is probably the problem. The layer is being loaded with a script tag. Do you know of some documentation explaining how to load a layer correctly?

Comment: You load a layer the same way you load any other AMD module, which is why they should only be created out of modules that already exist.

Comment: Such a good answer.  These clarifications are not obvious, to me at least, in the dojo docs.